# descriptions of the bitcoin-qt files

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

bitcoin-qt creates files under `~/.bitcoin/` in my file system. i know that the `~/.bitcoin/blocks/blk*dat` files contain the blockchain, but what do the following other files contain:

```
~/.bitcoin/blocks/rev*dat
~/.bitcoin/chainstate/*sst
~/.bitcoin/blocks/index/*sst
```

i know `sst` stands for "sorted string table" and i gather these files belong to a leveldb database, but i'd like to know in more detail what is in each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin data directory files details are here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory